# Nested routes in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm setting up some nested routes within React-Router (v0.11.6 is what I'm working against) but whenever I try and access one of the nested routes it triggers the parent route.

My routes look like this:

```
<Route handler={App}>
    <Route name="home" path="/" handler={availableRoutes.Splash} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={availableRoutes.Splash} />

    <Route name="dashboard" handler={availableRoutes.Dashboard}>
        <Route name="dashboard-child" handler={availableRoutes.DashboardChild} />
   </Route>

    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

If I collapse the routes up so it looks like:

```
<Route handler={App}>
    <Route name="home" path="/" handler={availableRoutes.Splash} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={availableRoutes.Splash} />

    <Route name="dashboard" handler={availableRoutes.Dashboard} />
    <Route name="dashboard-child" path="/dashboard/dashboard-child" handler={availableRoutes.DashboardChild} />

    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

It works fine. The reason I was nesting was because I will have multiple children under the "dashboard" and wanted them all prefixed with `dashboard` in the URL.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The configuration isn't about the routing (despite the name) but more about the layouts driven by paths.

So, with this configuration:

```
<Route name="dashboard" handler={availableRoutes.Dashboard}>
  <Route name="dashboard-child" handler={availableRoutes.DashboardChild} />
</Route>
```

It is saying that `dashboard-child` is to be embedded inside `dashboard`.  How this works is that if `dashboard` has something like this:

```
<div><h1>Dashboard</h1><RouteHandler /></div>
```

and `dashboard-child` has:

```
<h2>I'm a child of dashboard.</h2>
```

Then for the path `dashboard` there is no embedded child due to no matching path, resulting in this:

```
<div><h1>Dashboard</h1></div>
```

And for the path `dashboard/dashboard-child` the embedded child has a matching path, resulting in this:

```
<div><h1>Dashboard</h1><h2>I'm a child of dashboard.</h2></div>
```

Comment: @bjfletcher, could you clarify, how routes and layout should look if I have such example:  layout 3 levels in depth,  and when I'm switching between 3rd level routers then 2nd level parent component shouldn't be re-rendered.

Comment: @MihailZheludev Absolutely. Here's easy way to find out: modify some text in that parent component. Then play with 3rd level component.  The modification should remain and not re-rendered.

Comment: @bjfletcher, I understand it, but I have problem like I described above. I have 2 levels and all the application from root element to last child is being rendered for every transition to child

Comment: @MihailZheludev That shouldn't happen. I suggest comparing your app code with a similar sample from react-router, trying to see what's the offending code that is causing the "full page reload". Divide & conquer the app to be as similar as possible with the sample, and the offending code will hopefully become apparent. HTH.

Comment: @bjfletcher, [there is that issue we talked about](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZNlHN5ORvn46SkSid25?p=preview)

Answer (score 13):

Here's an update to @bjfletcher's answer for react-router 1.0.0. As noted in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/c27b018268864c8671c4cc3c6c6819bb255114df/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#routehandler):

> `RouteHandler` is gone. `Router` now automatically populates `this.props.children` of your components based on the active route.

So instead of

`<div><h1>Dashboard</h1><RouteHandler /></div>`

you would use:

`<div><h1>Dashboard</h1>{this.props.children}</div>`

Comment: What if you just want nested routes in the url but want `{this.props.children}` do be the only component?

Comment: a solution I found is to contol it in the parent component, at the render function, with a code snippet such as: `if(this.props.children) return (this.props.children);`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I think that following snippet could work for you:

```
...
<Route name="dashboard">
  <Route path="/" handler={availableRoutes.Dashboard}/>
  <Route name="dashboard-child" path="dashboard-child" handler={availableRoutes.DashboardChild}/>

  <DefaultRoute handler={availableRoutes.Dashboard}/>
</Route>
...
```