# React router - Nested routes not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My goal is to have http://mydomain/route1 render React component Component1 and http://mydomain/route2 render Component2. So, I thought it's natural to write the routes like the following:

```
    <Route name="route1" handler={Component1}>
        <Route name="route2" handler={Component2} />
    </Route>

    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home} />
  </Route>
```

http://mydomain/route1 works as expected but http://mydomain/route2 renders Component1 instead.

Then I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612765/nested-routes-in-react-router) and changed the routes to as follows:

```
    <Route name="route1" path="route1" handler={Component1} />
    <Route name="route2" path="route1/route2" handler={Component2} />

    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home} />
  </Route>
```

Both http://mydomain/route2 and http://mydomain/route2 work as expected now. However, I don't understand why the former one does not work while it looks more logical and neater to me.

The nested syntax works for "/" and "route1" so why not "route1" and "route2"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that in nested routes, the router will try to mount all the components that match the hierarchy. This is best used when you want to nest components inside each other... but if you want two separate routes to match different components, they will need to be their own routes.

```
<Route handler={App}>
  <Route path="route1" handler={Component1} />
  <Route path="/route1/route2" handler={Component2} />
  <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home} />
</Route>
```

`Component2` will mount (inside of `App`) when the URL is `/route1/route2`.

If you wanted to nest the components, you would need to add `<RouteHandler/>` to `Component1` so it would render `Component2` inside of it.

The reason this works is because nesting components are not the same as nesting URLs and can be handled separately by the router. Sometimes you want the components to nest but not necessarily the URLs, and vice versa.

Comment: Nice, concise explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

When using hierarchical routes where there is navigation that needs the correct active states, a better approach is to do the following (using the syntax for RR2):

```
<Route path="route1">
    <IndexRoute component={Component1}/>
    <Route path="route2" component={Component2} />
 </Route>
```

This way when the URL is `/route1/route2` any navigation links for `route1` will correctly have an active state.

Answer (score 9):

I was solving similar problem (`Component2` was not rendered) and nested routes wasn't working because I forgot to render `{this.props.children}` in `Component1`