# React-router: How to pass `components` prop to ancestor?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently, I have a structure similar to

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="page1" components={{content: C1, aside: A1}} />
  <Route path="page2" components={{content: C2, aside: A2}} />

  <Route path="page3" components={{content: C3, aside: A3}} >
    <Route path="page3-sub" components={{content: C3Sub, aside: A3Sub}} />
  </Route>

</Route>
```

With this routing configuration `page3-sub`'s components don't make it to `App`: they are being "overwritten" by `page3`'s. Is there any way to keep this routing structure **and** use `page3-sub`'s components?

Answer (score 0):

I cant test this but I believe you just need to un-nest them:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="page1" components={{content: C1, aside: A1}} />
  <Route path="page2" components={{content: C2, aside: A2}} />
  <Route path="page3" components={{content: C3, aside: A3}} />
  <Route path="page3-sub" components={{content: C3Sub, aside: A3Sub}}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, as stated in the question, I need that particular routing structure, but thanks!

Comment: Thats doable too. Im sure I recall somebody having the exact issue you are having in react-routers github help channels and they resolved it by using this method. Update your path accordingly like so:
<Route path="page3/page3-sub" components={{content: C3Sub, aside: A3Sub}}/>
Im sorry if I've mislead you on this though, as I said, im not in a position to test.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303221/react-router-nested-routes-not-working

Comment: Thanks! Did not find that post while researching the topic!

Comment: Did this resolve the issue for you? (and if it did can I beg you for an upvote/accepted answer?)

Comment: Comments can't be marked as an answer :(

Comment: But this IS my answer.

Comment: ...By that I mean, the answer above, not the subsequent comments like this one.