# ReactJs - Complex tree route

Tags: javascript, routes, react-router, reactjs

I have this `Route` configuration (builded with `react-router`)

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
        <Route path="studio" component={Studio}>
            <Route path="/studio/detail" component={Calendar} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

and the `component` App renders this:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><Link className="menu-link" ref="menu" to="/studio">Studio</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div id="content-wrapper">{this.props.children}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

My route `/studio/detail` is called from another component but when i try to see it i don't see my page detail, instead i see its parent `/studio` page.

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27670456/4741567 . I think this is what might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you nest your `<Route>`s as above, React Router will nest the corresponding components, per https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#decoupling-the-ui-from-the-url.

If you need to not nest `<Calendar>` under `<Studio>`, then don't nest the corresponding routes.