# What is wrong with this react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this routes config with `react-router`:

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={PoApp}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route name="category" path="notices/:category" component={Category}>
                <Route name="notice" path=":id" component={Content} />
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('poApp'));
```

For `/` and `notices/:category` works fine

But for :id (which would be /notices/:category/:id) it still loads the `Category` Component. What is wrong?

I let here some examples of how should work, if I didn't be clear:

`/` => PoApp

`/notices/cars` => Category

`/notices/cars/2` => Content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612765/nested-routes-in-react-router?rq=1), nested routes are for embedding nested components and not to refer to different components at nested routes.

In your case, `Category` component should have a placeholder for child component(like `<RouteHandler />` or `{this.props.children}` depending on your router version). Then with nested route appropriate child component will be embedded into the parent component.